# Installing the newest KeePass for Mac OSX from source

Tags: osx-leopard, keepass, mono-framework

I've transitioned our passwords to KeePass.  LastPass looks cool, but I prefer a system where we control the database locally rather than it being kept in the cloud.  I have a windows and Linux system and both are able to access our KeePass database easily.  On my Linux system (Ubuntu), I simply installed KeePass via synaptic and it just worked.

So everything was working great, until my wife tried to set up things on her MacBook to access the database.  Huge problems.  It was so easy on Linux that I didn't expect there to be issues there.  In case it's helpful, she's running a fresh install of Mac OSX 10.5.8, Leopard.

We simply went to the download site for KeePass:
http://keepass.info/download.html

Clicked on the link titled *KeePass 2.x for Mac OS X* from which we retrieved *Mono 2.10.5* and *KeePass 2.18* from that site (the packages posted there at the time of this writing).

Mono installed without problems (at least, none that we saw).

She opened the KeePass image and dragged it to the Application side, unpackaging it there.  According to the instructions on the KeePass installation instructions, she opened a terminal, changed to the directory in /Applications containing KeePass.exe, and ran it through mono:

```
mono KeePass.exe
```

No application opens at all - we see a blip for it, but then it immediately goes away, indicating to us that it is crashing.

Also disconcerting, I see that people are throwing fits about copy-and-paste not working for KeePass 2.18 on Mac OSX.  Judging from the 2.19 addresses the copy/paste issue.  I'm hoping that version will solve all our issues.

So here's my question: how can I try out 2.19 on her system.  It doesn't seem to be packaged like the 2.18 one is.  But we're not scared of building it.  I see that the source for 2.19 is [here](http://keepass.info/download.html) (at the bottom of the page).  Can I just download that to her machine somewhere and run something to build it?  I'm familiar with automake but not with building .NET source, so please answer gently if this is stupidly easy. :^)

btw: **tomorrow's my wife's birthday**, and this is getting her down.  If you know how to navigate these issues, it would be a nice birthday gift for her.

---

Update

I'll post this since it might be helpful to someone else:

I got KeePass 2.18 to run by updating Mono to 2.10.9 (rather than the 2.10.5 given by the site above).  With the later version of Mono, it runs without crashing.

And yet, I do see the copy and paste issue that others see.  I can open a database on her machine, but the incorrect data get's copied.

So again, can someone help me install KeePass 2.19?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have mono you don't need OS X packaged version of keepass, compiling from source is also unnecessary. Easiest way to test if 2.19 does what you need is to download zipped version of it.

When zip-package is extracted you can simply run:

```
mono Keepass.exe
```

IF latest version is working for you then creating a small script and adding it to dock to launch the keepass should not be too big of a problem.

Comment: You did it, Ahe!  I guess I should blush that it was so simple. Oh well, thanks for the birthday present for my wife.